# wrapping DB in docker image

Tags: docker

I just can't get it. As much as I understand docker containers are stateless and when you stop a container any state will be lost. What is the idea and the approaches behind wrapping DB in Image and how the data is saved? I can't find a clear explanation on this topic. Could somebody explain the basics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data of the DB that runs inside your container must be stored either in a so called *volume container* or in a host folder that you *mount* into your container.

For further information please refer to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/).

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by using Docker's [volume sharing feature](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems). [This](https://docs.docker.com/examples/postgresql_service/) is the Docker's official documentation to dockerize PostgreSQL.

Comment: So the idea is to save the data on the host machine by sharing data dir with the container? Is this correct? Sorry if the question is stupid, but I've red this docs and there are no clear statements about the whole concept, just a lot of obscure settings.

Comment: At first, any data in a container are somehow stored in the host, right? You can see the detail by running `docker inspect <container>`. With  acceptance on this point, the key idea is to *expose* the container's directory outside the container.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't red about the data volumes, which are separate concept used to persist data. But without this data volumes, if you stop a container you will loose everything which is accumulated after an image is started. At least I understand it so. May be I am not right

Comment: You can mount host's directory to the container using `docker run -v <host_directory>:<container_directory>`. So the data written to the *<container_directory>* is persisted in the host's *<host_directory>*.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure there is a clear explanation. The idea is that you create 2 docker images.  Say you are running Postgres, you would create the first image as your data container.  You 'docker run' it, but, it doesn't do anything (perhaps your command is sleep infinity which will keep docker happy).  Then, you run the container again, this time you mount the volumes from the current running container.  This mounts the volume from the first instance into the second. Here is an example where I do it:

[db container](https://github.com/lgfausak/abroute_docker_db)

The container I run first declares a few volumes that will be mounted my the second container, here is how I run the first container :

```
docker run -name abdata tacodata/abroute_docker_db
```

And then the second:

```
docker run -name pgsql --volumes-from abdata tacodata/abroute_docker_postgres absql
```

The key to the --volumes-from comes when you construct the image in the first place from the Dockerfile, here is the Dockerfile from my first image:

```
FROM tacodata/abroute-docker-base

MAINTAINER Greg Fausak <greg@tacodata.com>

RUN pip install web.py

COPY PG.sql /usr/local/etc/
COPY abinit abadm.py /usr/local/bin/

VOLUME ["/var/lib/postgresql"]
VOLUME ["/etc/postgresql"]
VOLUME ["/run/postgresql"]

ENTRYPOINT ["abinit"]
```

Using this technique, when I run the second image, and do the --volumes-from the_first_image, that mounts each of the VOLUME declared in the Dockerfile from the first image to the second.

One of the cute things you get from this kind of approach is that the first image can do things like create the database, create users, etc.  So the second image need only be concerned with running the application.  In my ENTRYPOINT I set up a file semaphore.  When the first image is 'done', it touches a file, the second image waits on the creation of that file.  So the second image doesn't start before the first is complete.

Long story even longer, I'm with you.  This simply moves the problem.  Instead of having persistent data in the container which runs the database I have persistent data in a different container.

Comment: Thank you for your effort to explain this.